# Unable to get the attribute value using jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a attribute value from my dom element, but i am getting result as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'
```

I am not able to get the attribute value at all.. what is the issue..?

here my my code :

HTML:

```
<div class="label" aria-label="Logo">
    <div class="trunc-string">
        <div class="start denali-tooltip tooltip-on-truncate"><span>Logo</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var x =  $("div.label")[0];
console.log (x.attr("aria-label"));
```

any one direct me in the right way please..?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/m35RM/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$("div.label:eq(0)");` instead of `$("div.label")[0];`

```
var x =  $("div.label:eq(0)");
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/m35RM/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this,

```
        $(function(){
            // will give you pure javascript(DOM) object,so use getAttribute().
            var x =  $("div.label")[0];
            console.log(x.getAttribute("aria-label"));
            //using jquery
            console.log($(x).attr("aria-label"));

        })
```

Comment: *"will give you pure javascript object"* I think you mean "DOM element" instead. A jQuery object is also a "pure JavaScript object".

Comment: yes because jquery object is also one kind of javascript object

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var x =  $("div.label"); //or $("div.label:eq(0)")
console.log (x.attr("aria-label"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m35RM/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x =  $("div.label:eq(0)");
console.log (x.attr("aria-label"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x =  $("div.label")[0];
//^^^^^ by this you get a object with html of .label


console.log ($(x).attr("aria-label"));
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^then use as a jquery object and apply their method
```

**[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/m35RM/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

if you multiple `div.label` element and you want to get value according to its node position, You can go with

```
var x =  $("div.label:eq(0)");
console.log (x.attr("aria-label"));
```

Otherwise if there is only one `div.label`element, You can go with

```
var x =  $("div.label");
console.log (x.attr("aria-label"));
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will return the attribute value of the *first* selected element, if used as getter:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

So all you really have to do is

```
$("div.label").attr("aria-label");
```

If you want to filter selection to only include the first element (because you want to use it somewhere else), you can use [`.first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
 var x = $("div.label").first();
```

or [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
 var x = $("div.label").eq(0);
```

---

The reason why you get the error is that `$(...)[i]` returns the selected *DOM element* at that position. DOM elements don't have an `.attr` method.